# In Arch linux -- systemd, in FreeBsd -?

Tags: freebsd, systemd, arch-linux

In Arch linux, for example, when I'm running my web application on it, I create a systemd service so it'll be supervised and restarted when needed. On FreeBsd systemd isn't installed by default, then, what's the alternative or how am I supposed to do the same thing in FreeBsd?

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD service management system is called `rc`. FreeBSD Handbook has a [nice explanation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-rcd.html) of it.

To make a service for your application you need to write a rc script. You can take `openvpn` or many system scripts as example.

As for systemd, there is no way to run it on FreeBSD, as it is too Linux-centric.

Comment: yeah, but what should I add to "rc.conf"? A path to my executable web app file or what? My web application executable file itself isn't a service, it's a normal executable file, whereas everything in rc.conf is a service.

Comment: As I said, you need to write a service script for your app. Do `pkg install openvpn` and take a look at `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/openvpn` script.